# Rails many to many through association - can't set relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want to create an app with an invitation system where users can invite members to different teams. But I can't get it working. I have four model objects - `User`, `Team`, `Member (join table between User & Team)` & `Invitation` - these look something like this:

```
#User 

has_many :members
has_many :teams, through: :members
accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
accepts_nested_attributes_for :members

has_many :sent_invitations, class_name: "Invitation", foreign_key: "sender_id"
has_many :invitations

#Team

has_many :members
has_many :users, through: :members
has_many :invitations

#Invitation

has_one :sender, class_name: "User"
has_one :recipient, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :team
```

I have an `ActionMailer` that sends invitations to users, each `Invitation` object has a token. When I create new users I want to add the invited users to the correct team - in a safe way. My user controller looks like this:

```
# GET /users/new
def new
  @user = User.new
  if params[:invitation_token]
    @user.email = Invitation.find_by_token(params[:invitation_token]).recipient_email
    @invitation = Invitation.where(token: params[:invitation_token])
  else
    @team = @user.teams.build
  end
end

# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user

      # Private method for adding users to their teams.
      add_to_team

      [...]


def add_to_team
  if @invitation
    puts "Should add to team" # But never gets called!
    @user.teams << @invitation.team
    @user.invitations << @invitation
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

It seems like my if statement in `add_to_team` never evaluates to true. My `@invitation` is nil for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Tried to my my `@invitation` instance variable to my create action instead. Like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if params[:invitation_token]
    @invitation = Invitation.where(token: params[:invitation_token])
  end

 #And
 def add_to_team
   if @invitation
     # Never gets called
     @user.teams << @invitation.team
     @user.invitations << @invitation
     puts "Invited by team: #{@invitation.team.name}"
     @user.save!
   end
 end
```

But the code inside the if statement still doesn't get called.

Comment: Are you ever loading `@invitation` in the `create` action? `create` does not have access to any instance variables only loaded by `new`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to move the instance variable to my create action instead, but the code inside my if statement never gets called. Update my question. Any more ideas? :)

Comment: How are you linking to the `create` action? Does the `create` action have access to `params[:invitation_token]`? You're also going to run into a problem where `Invitation.where(...)` will return an activerecord relation, not the individual invitation object, so stuff like `@invitation.team` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing you need to understand is new action and create action although defined in same controller get called at different times so can not share any variables like you usually do in Ruby.

There are two ways to share such data. One is to add a hidden field to new user form and set it to appropriate value in new action. Then access it from create action.

```
# new action
@invitation_token = params[:invitation_token]

# in form view
# add hidden field for invitation_token initialized to @invitation_token
# like following
<%= hidden_field_tag :invitation_token, @invitation_token %>
```

Then your code accessing `params[:invitation_token]` will work in create action.

Alternatively, use session variable to pass token from new action to create action.

```
# in new action
if params[:invitation_token]
  # other code
  session[:invitation_token] = params[:invitation_token]
else
 # other code
end


# in create action
if session[:invitation_token]
  @invitation = Invitation.where(token: session[:invitation_token])
  session[:invitation_token] = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have created a hidden field. The URL contains a token param but this if statement won't evaluate to true when placed in my  create action: `if params[:invitation_token] ...`

Comment: What do you mean by URL contains token. Normally you won't see the token in URL while invoking create action as it would be POST request and you would have to inspect the Network tab. What do you see in development log i.e. terminal where you ran rails server? What are params for that request.

Comment: I mean that I'm sure that the URL contains a `param` with a `token`. It looks like: `/signup?invitation_token=52d1756f117c5ea0280a1ddd12a2f26d1bade9ed`. But still it's nil in my controller.

Comment: That is the URL of the page which shows the form right? Or is it the URL when you submit the form?

Comment: When the form is shown, and it's the token I want to use when I submit it. In my form view I have this code: `- if  params[:invitation_token].present? = f.hidden_field :invitation_token, value: params[:invitation_token]`

Comment: You are creating invitation_token inside user then. That means you can access invitation_token in create action by using params[:user][:invitation_token] You can verify it by checking HTML of the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54860/discussion-between-amitamb-and-anders).